# pyspark dataframe -- Why are null values recognized differently in below scenarios?

Tags: apache-spark, null, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Why `isNull()` behaves differently in below scenarios?

- PySpark 1.6
- Python 2.6.6

Definition of two dataframes:

```
df_t1 = sqlContext.sql("select 1 id, 9 num union all select 1 id, 2 num union all select 2 id, 3 num")
df_t2 = sqlContext.sql("select 1 id, 1 start, 3 stop union all select 3 id, 1 start, 9 stop")
```

Scenario 1:

```
df_t1.join(df_t2, (df_t1.id == df_t2.id) & (df_t1.num >= df_t2.start) & (df_t1.num <= df_t2.stop), "left").select([df_t2.start, df_t2.start.isNull()]).show()
```

Output 1:

```
+-----+-------------+
|start|isnull(start)|
+-----+-------------+
| null|        false|
|    1|        false|
| null|        false|
+-----+-------------+
```

Scenario 2:

```
df_new=df_t1.join(df_t2, (df_t1.id == df_t2.id) & (df_t1.num >= df_t2.start) & (df_t1.num <= df_t2.stop), "left")
```

Output 2:

```
+-----+-------------+
|start|isnull(start)|
+-----+-------------+
| null|         true|
|    1|        false|
| null|         true|
+-----+-------------+
```

Scenario 3:

```
df_t1.join(df_t2, (df_t1.id == df_t2.id) & (df_t1.num >= df_t2.start) & (df_t1.num <= df_t2.stop), "left").filter("start is null").show()
```

Output 3:

```
+---+---+----+-----+----+
| id|num|  id|start|stop|
+---+---+----+-----+----+
|  1|  9|null| null|null|
|  2|  3|null| null|null|
+---+---+----+-----+----+
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @zero323 for editing.